# Can MOCA be connected like this?

Tags: networking, fios

Finally moving to a house from an apartment for better or worse...

the internet provider is verizon fios and it provides an ethernet plug in the corner of the basement... not very centrally located for a router

I was thinking I could take use the below approach

wall --> verizon ONT --ethernet--> moca --coax---> moca --ethernet--> wan port of wifi router (centrally located)

assuming the above works, could I then use a moca at other locations in the house to essentially convert the unused coax to ethernet ports?

it would just seem as though the first moca is injecting the wan port signal into the coax as opposed to the router or perhaps I simply don't have a deep enough understanding of the underlying technology/networking... :(

Comment: What are you using to do this? I know it can kinda be done with the old mi424 VZ routers. I've only done A-B with them, not to multiple points. Note, you can get verizon to switch the ONT to coax, then you can put the router wherever is most convenient. Depending on the speed of the plan, and in general, Ethernet is better.